# Access to read gmail-imap from Heroku just started to fail

Tags: python, heroku, gmail-imap

I have a Python app that is scheduled to read email from google via IMAP every 10 minutes, processes the body of the email and spit data out to one of a number of Google spreadsheets.  This works perfectly on my Mac. Until November 3 it ran perfectly on Heroku until it started to get rejected with the dreaded message:

Cannot access email server imap.gmail.com -- [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)'

No emails have been sent from Google to give a warning.  As I said, it still runs perfectly on the Mac when run manually - same code unchanged.

Any suggestions on what can be done to restore service?

Comment: Note sure if this is useful but I recently tried using smtp with gmail and got rejected by google because I didn't have a recognized domain/app.  A message from Google said I needed to go into my security settings and enable "less secure applications".  I ended up switching to my msn account and haven't had any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the observation but, sadly, I have to stay with Google as it is a small business email account where this occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I tried scheduling my app to run every hour rather than every 10 minutes.  That seemed to fix the problem for a week.  Now it is back to refusing access again, while running the same code on my Mac continues to work.  Given that the app reads less than 100 emails a day this is pretty weird IF the app is being blocked due to 'suspicious activity'.

Nothing conclusive yet.  Still looking for suggestions.